# Video Feedback Loop with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, feedback

I am trying to create a digital video feedback loop between two computers.

What I mean by this is the following:

[image: digital video feedback loop]

I attempted several combinations of protocols and video formats and I found out this is the closest I can get. The original video was an "mov" but I had to convert it to .ts in order to get this far, had other issues when using mov or mp4.

I ran the commands in this order to make sure tcp listeners were up before the clients.

#### On Local Computer

```
# Command 1: Temporary attempt to capture output of loop
ffmpeg -i 'udp://0.0.0.0:6002?listen&overrun_nonfatal=1' -c copy out.ts
```

```
# Command 2: Receives stream from remote host and forwards back to beginning of loop
ffmpeg -i tcp://0.0.0.0:6001?listen -f mpegts udp://localhost:6002
```

#### On Remote Computer

```
#  Command 3: Receives stream from local host and returns stream to another ffmpeg instance
ffmpeg -i tcp://0.0.0.0:6000?listen -f mpegts tcp://<local.ip>:6001
```

#### On Local Computer

```
# Command 4: Sends stream to remote host
ffmpeg -re -i in.ts  -f mpegts tcp://<remote.ip>:6000
```

The steps above don't quite complete the feedback loop, but they do result in a successful video `out.ts`

Then I tried to modify Command 4 so that it could merge both a file and a udp stream, this is a naive attempt I know, I am not very good with ffmpeg.

```
 ffmpeg \
    -re -i in.ts -i udp://0.0.0.0:6002 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=540x960[top]; \
        [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=540x960, \
             format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]; \
        [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1" \
    -f mpegts tcp://<remote.ip>:6000
```

The result was that the command hung waiting for a data on the udp port, which makes sense in hindsight.

I would like to know:

- Can this be done at all? If so, what do I need to change?
- Do I need to abandon ffmpeg for this task and look into something else?

If you're asking why would I do this, the answer is there is no good reason other than I am curious to know if it's possible and what results it would yield.